# How to make the size of PDF output wider?

Tags: paper-size

Is there a way to make the PDF width and height larger?

Comment: You mean increase the paper size? This can be done using the `geometry` package.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can adjust the settings given below. I think they are self-explanatory.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage%
[%
left=2cm,% left margin
right=2cm,% right margin
top=3cm, % top margin
bottom=3cm,% bottom margin
a3paper% other options: a0paper, a1paper, a2paper, a3paper, a4paper, a5paper, a6paper, and many more.
]{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum}% to get dummy contents, you might not need this of course!
\begin{document}
\lipsum% to render dummy contents.
\end{document}
```

Other settings such as gutter, marginpar width, `marginparsep` etc are also available.

If you need custom paper size, then use `paperwidth` and `paperheight` instead of `a*paper`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to resize paper you can use:

```
\setlength{\paperwidth}{25cm} % set dimension of \paperwidth to 25 cm
\addtolength{\paperheight}{1in} % enlarge \paperheight by 1 inch
```

for pdfLaTeX you shall use lengths `\pdfpaperwidth` and `\pdfpaperheight`. My teacer uses this construction:

```
\ifx\pdfoutput\undefined % LaTeX is used, pdf sizes are undefined
\else% pdfLaTeX is used, pds sizes are defined
 \setlength{\pdfpaperwidth}{100em}
 \addtolength{\pdfpaperheight}{10mm}
\fi
```

If you just want to put more text in standard paper (i.e. A4, A5) there are lenghts like `\textwidth`, `\textheight` and many others. see [Page dimensions](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Page_Layout#Page_dimensions) on Wikipedia

PS: First part is optional, second part is mandatory because LaTeX's paper sizes are defined by `\documentclass[/size/paper]` option so that you have to define new layout by yourself.

PSS: all the sizes like `\textwidth` can be used to define the others. For example `\includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{image/address}` typesets image with width of one half of paragaph, or `\setlength{\paperheight}{2\paperwidth}`...

Comment: Changing the `\paperwidth` and `\paperheight` wouldn't change the other correlated length like `\textwidth` and `\textheight`, would it? I recommend to do this only using the `geometry` package which will adjust all other length accordantly.

Comment: The `\ifx\pdfoutput\undefined` test gives wrong results. The correct way is to use the **ifpdf** package.

Answer (score 0):

Here is method without using a package:

```
\pdfpagewidth 9in
\pdfpageheight 12in
```