# How define a fixed width page, but length > some minimum length, but only as long as needed

Tags: margins, geometry

This recent question on [how to increase the width of the output](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19660/how-to-make-the-size-of-pdf-output-wider), and this earlier question on [how to increase the length of the output](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16316/how-to-specify-a-very-long-page) reminded me of something I have been wondering: I would like to fix the width and have the length to be longer than some minimum length, but only as long as necessary.

So far I have been using the `geometry` package to fix the width, and set the page length to be very long as per the above links, and this has been working. However, I would like to not have the extra blank space at the bottom for very short pages.

This is intended to generate individual pages for on screen viewing, and not a long document. Hence the desire for a single "page".

Comment: @Peter: `\newgeometry` and `\restoregeometry` from **geometry** could be what you are looking for?

Comment: But how do I determine how long to set the page? The page length is not fixed. If I add more text I want the page length to grow, and if I delete text I want the page length to shrink (but not shrink below a certain minimum)

Comment: @Peter `paperheight=200cm`?

Comment: See my answer to [Automatically increase PDF page height](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19237/automatically-increase-pdf-page-height/19241#19241) for a solution based on `preview`. The minimal length would need to be implemented in addition.

Comment: @egreg: I don't know upfront how long the page is going to be. So I need to wrap the `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` in a `\newcommand`, somehow determine the length that would take, then set the pagelength, and use the `\newcommand` to print the text.  Thats the theory, I just don't know how to do that..

Comment: @Martin: Have been looking at the link you posted but I can't seem to get that to work.

Comment: **Follow-up** Question: [Automate Fixed Width Page, length > some minimum length, but only as long as needed](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27041/automate-fixed-width-page-length-some-minimum-length-but-only-as-long-as-nee/).  **Related** Question: [Is there a documentclass that produces 'endless' pages?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64284/is-there-a-documentclass-that-produces-endless-pages).

Comment: Related Question: [How do I create a PDF document whose height exactly matches the contents?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/459459/4301).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{paperwidth=12cm,paperheight=\maxdimen,margin=1cm}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\setbox0=\vbox{
\lipsum
}
\dimen0=\dp0
\pdfpageheight=\dimexpr\ht0+2cm\relax
\ifdim\pdfpageheight<12cm \pdfpageheight=12cm \fi
\unvbox0\kern-\dimen0

\end{document}
```

If you try `\lipsum[1]` instead of `\lipsum` you get 12cm as height. This can be made automatic, I believe, by hooking into `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`.

Comment: This seems to do exactly what I need. I'll see if I can figure out how to wrap it around `\begin{document}` and `end{document}`. Thanks.

Comment: I am accepting this as it does what I want. I have not been able to automate this yet, but will keep trying to figure that out as it should not be that hard.

Comment: The automation is described here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/27057/7323