# Output a document containing a single vertical-infinite page

Tags: paper-size, dimensions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Automate Fixed Width Page, length > some minimum length, but only as long as needed](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27041/automate-fixed-width-page-length-some-minimum-length-but-only-as-long-as-nee)

Is there a way to output a document containing a SINGLE page (that contains the entire text which would normally break through let's say 10 A4 pages). I want the document width to be A4's width and the document height to be minimum height so that the document has a single page.

The motivation is: I don't really need pages (the document is not supposed to be printed) and my document contains lots of framed boxes that don't break across pages; so, there are large pieces of blank text when the next box doesn't fit the current page.

> EDIT: I know I can use \paperheight and \textheight but I don't wanna have to guess the value every time

Comment: This has been asked a couple of times before, see if http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49686/is-there-a-way-to-make-page-size-match-document-length helps

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).  I have been looking into exactly this and my last question on this subject provided an automated solution which I have been using: [Automate Fixed Width Page, length > some minimum length, but only as long as needed](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27041/automate-fixed-width-page-length-some-minimum-length-but-only-as-long-as-nee).

Comment: Nice! I'm sorry for the duplicate, I really didn't know what to look for. Although it wasn't my original intention, I really liked this screenread package. Thanks!