# Automatic page size to fit arbitrary content

Tags: crop

Is there a way to let LaTeX automatically set the page size to fit any given content? To be clear, the code should work for ALL types of contents and both crop and stretch the page depending on its size.

For example, this code:

```
\documentclass[varwidth=true, border=10pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
test & test & test & test
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

works as long as the table is not too large, but if the width is increased, for example like this:

```
\documentclass[varwidth=true, border=10pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttest & test & test & test
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

then the page is not (sufficiently) increased in size, but the table is cut off on the right side.

Is there a good way to do this for all cases?

Comment: Zoom out Zoom out

Comment: `varwidth=\maxdimen`, but there is an interesting effect if you need to set text in paragraphs (AKA the main purpose of using `varwidth`). ;-)

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\hoffset=-1in
\voffset=-1in
\setbox0\hbox{\begin{tabular}{cccc}
testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttest & test & test & test
\end{tabular}}
\pdfpageheight=\dimexpr\ht0+\dp0\relax
\pdfpagewidth=\wd0
\shipout\box0


\stop
```

Comment: This looks very strange, but it works... Why do you use \stop instead of \end{document}?

Comment: @lukas.coenig so you don't get a normal latex output page just the \shipout box

Comment: Great solution, thanks! It'll take some time until I understand it completely ;-)

Comment: Worth mentioning you need to be using `pdflatex` for this to work?

Comment: @LyndonWhite or xetex and at the time I wrote it probably also luatex, but now in luatex it would be `\pageheight` not `\pdfpageheight`

Comment: @David Carlisle Are you sure it works for every content? I tried it with normal text and with math expression and it worked, but when I tried it with a prooftree environment (using bussproofs package) it didn't work. Do you know why?

Comment: @MichaelNovak If you use `\setbox0\hbox` then its a horizontal box like `\mbox` so can not have vertical material, you could use `\vbox` instead (which will be full width) or you could nest a `\parbox` of specified width inside the hbox or .... So the code here will always make a page the size of a given box, but exactly how you make the box may depend on what you want to do.

Comment: What I want is a general way for any LaTex document to have a page width as long as needed in order to fit some graphical elements that in normal settings would raise an hbox error. The reason, I can't just configure my document so it doesn't have hbox errors is that this is a document I generate automatically by a python script. To be honest I don't entirely understand how I could do it. Do you have any idea how to do it? If so, I can create a question, because I think this could be useful for other people as well. By the way, your answer did work for me with multiple normal text lines.

Comment: there is another answer that shows how to ship out a page of normal width but as long as needed, I'll see if I can find..... @MichaelNovak

Comment: Oh, thank you so much! You have no idea how much you are helping me.

Comment: @MichaelNovak there is this one but that is not the one I had in mind https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49686/is-there-a-way-to-make-page-size-match-document-length/49688#49688

Comment: Oh, sorry it's not what I need. I need the same thing but instead of height width.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105133/discussion-between-david-carlisle-and-michael-novak).