# Set paperheight to (overall) textlength

Tags: geometry, automation, paper-size, height, relative

The page should when the text ends. So, that there is only one "page".
Don't worry. It's not for being printed.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

% Packages
\usepackage{lipsum,anyfontsize}
\usepackage[left=100px,right=100px,top=50px,bottom=50px,
paperwidth=1052px, paperheight=2250 px]{geometry} % max 15800 long

\begin{document}
 \fontsize{35}{42}\selectfont
 \lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```

[image]

This is for a board. You can upload pictures (yes, I can convert to pictures) and there is a perfect format (e.g. 1052px).

- It is very important that the units are in pixel.
- Advices for a better/easier font(-size) are appreciated but not needed (Font is unbelievable big as a cause of using px as unit).

I found this one [Is there a way to make "page" size match document length?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/49686/101053) but I does not help. Pls don't hate me.

Comment: is this one helpful?  [Is there a documentclass that produces 'endless' pages?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/64284/579)

Comment: it was answered here using [standalone](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/standalone/standalone.pdf) i can't find it now.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Not really. The solutions provided destroy my margins or don't work at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following example puts the page contents in a box, measures the box and ship outs a page with the corrected dimensions for the height of the page. The example assumes pdfTeX or LuaTeX. Here `\pdf(h,v)origin` and `\pdfpage(height,width)` are available to set the dimensions of the output page.

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum,anyfontsize}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\PrintPageHeight}{%
  \edef\PageHeightPt{\strip@pt\pdfpageheight pt}%
  \edef\PageHeightPx{%
    \strip@pt\dimexpr
      % scaling operation with doubled precision
      \pdfpageheight
      *\dimexpr1pt\relax
      /\dimexpr1px\relax
    \relax
    px
  }%
  \typeout{}%
  \typeout{=> Page height = \PageHeightPt\space = \PageHeightPx}%
  \typeout{}%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand*{\CheckPageHeight}{%
  \ifdim\pdfpageheight>15800px %
    \errmessage{Page height is too large!}%
  \fi
}

\setlength{\paperwidth}{1052px}
\setlength{\textwidth}{\paperwidth}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{-200px}% 2 * 100px

\setlength{\pdfhorigin}{100px}
\setlength{\pdfvorigin}{50px}
\setlength{\pdfpagewidth}{\paperwidth}

\newsavebox{\PageBox}
\newenvironment{board}{%
  \setbox\PageBox=\vbox\bgroup
  \begingroup % for color support
}{%
  \endgroup
  \egroup
  \setlength{\paperheight}{\ht\PageBox}%
  \addtolength{\paperheight}{\dp\PageBox}%
  \addtolength{\paperheight}{100px}% 2 * 50px
  \setlength{\pdfpageheight}{\paperheight}%
  \shipout\box\PageBox
  \PrintPageHeight
  \CheckPageHeight
}
\setlength{\maxdepth}{0pt}
\setlength{\topskip}{0pt}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
  \begin{board}
    \fontsize{35}{42}\selectfont
    \lipsum[1-5]
  \end{board}
\end{document}
```

Reported page height:

```
=> Page height = 2518.68092pt = 2509.26201px
```

Comment: Is there a way of knowing the actual page height? Or restrict the pageheight to 15800px?

Comment: @JoelDuscha I have updated the answer, it prints the page height in pt and px. Also the height is checked and an error is thrown, if the page height is too large.