# Is there a documentclass that produces 'endless' pages?

Tags: document-classes

Does anybody know of a documentclass that produces a page that has a fixed width and a variable length, depending on the actual content that needs to fit on the sheet? I'm trying to get something like a kind of scroll if possible.

Comment: `\documentclass[perforation holes=false]{toiletpaper}` :P

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE, please provide [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: @percusse: You nailed it! `:D`

Comment: @HiggsBoson: see percusse's comment, that's the MWE! `:)`

Comment: related: [What's the absolute largest paper size permissible with pdflatex?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/420/whats-the-absolute-largest-paper-size-permissible-with-pdflatex) and [Is there a way to make “page” size match document length?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49686/is-there-a-way-to-make-page-size-match-document-length)

Comment: Please upload the document class created in the accepted answer to CTAN. I also want to make use of it.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/19721/4427 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/27057/4427

Comment: possible duplicate of [Automate Fixed Width Page, length > some minimum length, but only as long as needed](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27041/automate-fixed-width-page-length-some-minimum-length-but-only-as-long-as-nee)

Answer (score 9):

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeatletter
\newbox\p@ge
\newenvironment{page}{\setbox\p@ge\hbox\bgroup}%
  {\egroup\setbox\p@ge\hbox{\raise\dp\p@ge\box\p@ge}\pdfpagewidth\wd\p@ge%
  \pdfpageheight\ht\p@ge\shipout\box\p@ge}
\makeatother
\AtBeginDocument{\pdfhorigin 00pt\pdfvorigin 0pt}
\begin{document}
 \begin{page}
  \begin{minipage}{5cm} 
    \lipsum[1-40]
  \end{minipage}
 \end{page}
\end{document}
```

I use that kind of trick to get a page as small or as big as I want, depending of the content. Hope this help !

You need to put your text in a minipage environment for usual vertical typesetting...

Answer (score 7):

You can put your whole content in a box of a given width. Then, retrieve the height of that box and use that dimension to fix the length of the pdf page. Finally, output the stored box to that page.

The following is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\setbox0=\vbox{
\parbox{6cm}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi vehicula lacinia convallis. Aliquam sapien nisi, vehicula ut posuere tristique, rutrum sit amet mi. Pellentesque quis quam quis purus malesuada dapibus. Proin eget sollicitudin erat. Nunc ut ante libero. Pellentesque massa risus, bibendum consequat tincidunt eu, rhoncus sit amet ligula. Proin pharetra bibendum urna, vitae tristique dolor auctor in. Curabitur turpis felis, fringilla quis vehicula et, elementum vitae tellus. Mauris non turpis lacus. Pellentesque lorem lacus, iaculis nec egestas vitae, varius eget risus. Nullam feugiat, justo vitae pretium eleifend, eros magna euismod ante, sit amet lacinia massa ligula vel nibh. Praesent dignissim, metus ut commodo tincidunt, odio risus consequat felis, sagittis sollicitudin dolor urna et magna. Phasellus ipsum dolor, interdum eget feugiat non, lacinia nec ligula. Duis commodo aliquam vulputate. Vestibulum tempus eleifend dui, sit amet suscipit tortor pharetra eu. Sed convallis ornare nulla cursus adipiscing. Nulla quis lectus eget arcu ornare sollicitudin. Quisque faucibus posuere lacus, et dapibus mauris iaculis sed. Aenean tellus nisi, sodales vitae dignissim accumsan, semper et lacus}

\parbox{6cm}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi vehicula lacinia convallis. Aliquam sapien nisi, vehicula ut posuere tristique, rutrum sit amet mi. Pellentesque quis quam quis purus malesuada dapibus. Proin eget sollicitudin erat. Nunc ut ante libero. Pellentesque massa risus, bibendum consequat tincidunt eu, rhoncus sit amet ligula. Proin pharetra bibendum urna, vitae tristique dolor auctor in. Curabitur turpis felis, fringilla quis vehicula et, elementum vitae tellus. Mauris non turpis lacus. Pellentesque lorem lacus, iaculis nec egestas vitae, varius eget risus. Nullam feugiat, justo vitae pretium eleifend, eros magna euismod ante, sit amet lacinia massa ligula vel nibh. Praesent dignissim, metus ut commodo tincidunt, odio risus consequat felis, sagittis sollicitudin dolor urna et magna. Phasellus ipsum dolor, interdum eget feugiat non, lacinia nec ligula. Duis commodo aliquam vulputate. Vestibulum tempus eleifend dui, sit amet suscipit tortor pharetra eu. Sed convallis ornare nulla cursus adipiscing. Nulla quis lectus eget arcu ornare sollicitudin. Quisque faucibus posuere lacus, et dapibus mauris iaculis sed. Aenean tellus nisi, sodales vitae dignissim accumsan, semper et lacus}

\parbox{6cm}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi vehicula lacinia convallis. Aliquam sapien nisi, vehicula ut posuere tristique, rutrum sit amet mi. Pellentesque quis quam quis purus malesuada dapibus. Proin eget sollicitudin erat. Nunc ut ante libero. Pellentesque massa risus, bibendum consequat tincidunt eu, rhoncus sit amet ligula. Proin pharetra bibendum urna, vitae tristique dolor auctor in. Curabitur turpis felis, fringilla quis vehicula et, elementum vitae tellus. Mauris non turpis lacus. Pellentesque lorem lacus, iaculis nec egestas vitae, varius eget risus. Nullam feugiat, justo vitae pretium eleifend, eros magna euismod ante, sit amet lacinia massa ligula vel nibh. Praesent dignissim, metus ut commodo tincidunt, odio risus consequat felis, sagittis sollicitudin dolor urna et magna. Phasellus ipsum dolor, interdum eget feugiat non, lacinia nec ligula. Duis commodo aliquam vulputate. Vestibulum tempus eleifend dui, sit amet suscipit tortor pharetra eu. Sed convallis ornare nulla cursus adipiscing. Nulla quis lectus eget arcu ornare sollicitudin. Quisque faucibus posuere lacus, et dapibus mauris iaculis sed. Aenean tellus nisi, sodales vitae dignissim accumsan, semper et lacus}
}
\pdfpagewidth6.5cm
\pdfpageheight1.21\ht0
\hoffset=-2in
\voffset=-1.7in
\box0
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately I cannot paste an image with the result at this moment, but it is a pdf with a single and very long page.

However, this page is not "infinite", nor can it have an arbitrary length. We are limited by the size of TeX registers. I think that the limit is around 10 meters.

Comment: Hmmm... 10 m max?... That should do. `;)`

Comment: Strangely enough that produces 2 pages, when I compile, the first one being blank... Guess that's related to the box exceeding the default page length of `article`. (There is also the page number on the first page, more or less at the middle of the first page, where I believe the page should normally end.) With `\documentclass{standalone}` the overfull box error goes away and there is a single page, but the page width is too wide. Got a fix?

Comment: Sorry, I'm currently far from my computer, on a iPad, and I cannot check nor solve these issues. For the page number you can use `nopageno` package.

Comment: Why didn't you make it as a document class?

Comment: I only pasted a solution I had in my hard disk, from a similar problem I had time ago. You are welcome to make a class from it.

Comment: @JLDiaz : How do the parameters work? I'm trying to take my current document which has plenty of pagebreak problems and make it into a document with one page per chapter (because I only read my document on my computer anyway, so I just realized I don't need pages at all). My pages have variable length and I would like to have them of height "height of the content + a footer". Your example works for the first page but for the other pages I can't control the height of the page very well.

Answer (score 7):

If you want do it in ConTeXt, you can use the `TeXpage` mechanism:

```
\starttext
  \startTEXpage [offset=2cm, width=21cm]
    \dorecurse{100}{%
      \input knuth}
  \stopTEXpage
\stoptext
```

But the TeX limit also applies here. With particular PDF readers you will have problems displaying such long files, even if they generate without TeX errors.