# Infinite canvas

Tags: tikz-pgf, formatting, pdf

It seems that all LaTeX formatting assumes we will ultimately print the document but if the goal is to publish online - under some circumstances, we might desire to have all the document in one "infinite" page so the reader can scroll it. That is the idea behind [the infinite canvas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_canvas). How should go about to try to implement this idea in a TikZ picture? How to avoid the picture being cropped by the page length set by document class?

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/64284/7883

Comment: Standalone class has no built in limits, but you need a finite width (minipage) to get more than a single very wide line.

Comment: Online infinite page... hmm...well, a web page is just that. HTML is just better for this purpose than a PDF. (Nonetheless, I prefer read PDF that a web page in the screen, but a major  reason for that is that there are finite pages.)