# Why so much whitespace on left side of standalone document?

Tags: white-space

I'm getting whitespace on the left of a standalone document when rendering equations in the mode in which they are surrounded by [ and ] (I think that's the mode in which they are supposed to be on their own line. Any ideas how to prevent this?

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}    
\begin{document}    
\[ 2x + 8 + 3x = 6x \]    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't use `preview` and type the equation as `$\displaystyle ...$`

Comment: That worked. Can you add it as an answer? Also, why do so many standalone examples I've seen specify to use 'preview' (just curious).

Comment: I've never seen it before.  According to the manual: If enabled the class options varwidth, preview and beamer require
the package or class of the same name.  See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/244348/make-only-one-page-for-each-chapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, `preview` is not able to crop the part at the left of the display.

To be honest, I never use that option; it's easier to use inline math mode, with `\displaystyle` to emulate a display.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}
\begin{document}
$\displaystyle 2x + 8 + 3x = 6x$
\end{document}
```

For alignments you can use the inner forms, for instance

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}
\begin{document}
$\begin{gathered}
  2x + 8 + 3x = 6x \\
  5x + 8 = 6x
\end{gathered}$

\end{document}
```

No `\displaystyle` is needed, because it's done by default in these environments.