# Fitting two pages into one

Tags: spacing

I have been working on my personal CV for quite a while and now I am stuck at this point where I can not fit two pages into one. As you can see in the link below the section that I am trying to squish into a single page is roughly small, so I reckon that there may be one solution for that.

I provided code : [here](https://codeshare.io/G73Z6k)

First I have tried to decrease the spacing size between items at the beginning of the list under the section "Linguistics":

```
\itemsep -0.5em \vspace{-0.5em}
```

Then I have tried to use:

```
\enlargethispage{\baselineskip}
```

None of the methods worked. If you have any ideas of how am I supposed to modify the code I would appreciate that!

Comment: You can add  `\setlength\itemsep{0.01em}` after each `\resumeSubHeadingListStart` which will minimize the space between the items, but you will have to shorten your CV anyways to fit in on one cite.

Comment: To literally fit two pages into one, use pdfpages.  See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/244348/make-only-one-page-for-each-chapter