# Never break a page unless explicitly told so, expand the margins to fit the content, and have mixed margins in the same document

Tags: margins, page-breaking

The first part of this question is basically this question: [Absolutely, definitely, preventing page break](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94699/absolutely-definitely-preventing-page-break)

Partially modified MWE from that answer,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newenvironment{absolutelynopagebreak}
  {\par\nobreak\vfil\penalty0\vfilneg
   \vtop\bgroup}
  {\par\xdef\tpd{\the\prevdepth}\egroup
   \prevdepth=\tpd}
\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]

    \begin{absolutelynopagebreak}
        \raggedbottom
        \lipsum[1-3]\lipsum*[4]\lipsum[1-3]\lipsum*[4]\lipsum[1-3]\lipsum*[4]
    \end{absolutelynopagebreak}

    HERE WE RESTART \lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Except, this only accomplishes the `never break a page` part. It never breaks a page indeed, but you still have to calculate the margins manually.

[image: Screenshot of MWE]

I can extend this page with the margins package, manually. But I have to do it myself. Since latex knows when to break a page, it has to know the needed size for items. I am wondering if there is a way to automate this?

Basically, the case below is what I want to accomplish,

- Have one page with 10 lorem ipsums, this page should take as much space as 10 pages.
- Have the next page with 20 lorem ipsums, this page should take double the space.

This would require mixed margins within the same document as well.

Is this possible, even if only partially so?

I don't mind having to use a different rendering engine if there is a specific feature for this in either xetex or luatex.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try the standalone class along with a minipage for every chunk?

Comment: I think you are dreaming the impossible dream, although I am open to correction. A page has a physical size (typically A4 or letterpaper). To pack the text onto a page that would normally require 10 or 20 regular pages just eliminating all margins will not be sufficient. You would have to reduce the font size, perhaps to an unreadable value.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer No I haven't. minipage is not something I have used before actually. I will check it out. Thanks for the suggestion!
-Peter Wilson Well, the tex and the pdf produced in this question isn't something I intend to print. It is more like a list of notes. And I was thinking each subsection would be its own page(length of each being more like 3-4 pages), so that it would be easy to navigate in the pdf viewer without cuts(graphs and all). Sort of like an html page. I have a bunch of macros I have on tex that I enjoy, so even if it is not the exact use case of tex, it is useful to me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/244348/make-only-one-page-for-each-chapter

Comment: @John Kormylo Seems so. Sadly, now I have another problem. I already use some KOMA features, so I would like to use use the "scrartcl" class. I don't mind losing the margins and all that(I am familiar enough with koma to configure those from stratch), but it seems when I do `\documentclass[class=scrartcl,preview,pagesize=off]{standalone}`, I can't insert a page break at all. And without the preview part, there are no page breaks, and the text skips horizontally. Do you have any ideas how can I use -some- of the KOMA(even if partially broken) and insert a real page break?