# Formatting for on line viewing

Tags: formatting

I'd like to format a file for on line viewing - that is, make a PDF that looks good in Acrobat. I have been using LaTeX to format for printing, and it does a good job of that, but I can't seem to find information about formatting the PDF for use on line. How?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  Most browsers can view a pdf just fine without changing any formatting.  Is there something specific that looks wrong when you open the pdf in a browser?

Comment: They can see the PDF, but there are blank pages (like after a \part) and the margins are uneven -- they are formatted for printing.

Comment: That's how it will look in Acrobat as well.  To remove the blank pages, add `openany` as an option to your `\documentclass` command.  To have symmetrical margins, look into the `geometry` package.

Comment: Possibly related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/244348/make-only-one-page-for-each-chapter