# Can you get rid of pages (not page numbers, the actual pages)?

Tags: formatting, diagrams, line-breaking, page-breaking

I am writing a personal set of proofs that I will use in the future if I ever forget the concepts I am writing.

One thing is, I like the "blog format" of having a single white strip of text without page breaks.

The notes will always be in digital format and I am a bit sick of fighting latex formatting such that my diagrams end up in the pages that I want them to be in.

Is it possible to tell latex to create a "single very long page"?

Comment: LaTeX is "page oriented". For what you looking for is intended HTML language/documents. You can convert LaTeX to HTML.

Comment: How can I do that conversion?

Comment: Print the document and then use sticky tape? More seriously, my PDF browser displays an "infinite" scrollable pdf file, which is pretty close to what you want. Using the [geometry](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/geometry) package you can adjust the top and bottom page margins so that you will not see the page breaks, giving exactly what you want.

Comment: Search for "latex to html conversionˇ. Google gives more than 5 million results ...

Comment: Viewer has: View | Page Display | Enable Scrolling. FYI: To insert items inline, don't use the `figure` environment - it is a "float" and is designed to move to the best position for printing. Likewise with tables: just use a `tabular` not inside a table environment (they also float).

Comment: If the only problem is diagrams not ending up in the right spot, then you don't want them to be floating: don't use the figure or table environments (and use the caption package if you still need a caption).

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/244348/make-only-one-page-for-each-chapter  OTOH, you would have to define a lot more than just \chapter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `geometry` package to have very long pages. To display practice class solutions using a single page I use the following command:

```
\usepackage[margin=1cm,paperwidth=20cm,paperheight=110cm]{geometry}
```

The maximum length available is about `575cm`.