# Start new page with each section with new page geometry

Tags: page-breaking, geometry, section-titles

I would like to start each section on a new page and new geometry. For each section on a new page,  `\newcommand{\sectionbreak}{\clearpage}` is used but I can't change the page geometry.

Normally, 2.5 cm should be inside, but for section pages, it should be 5cm.

[image]

[image]

Is there a general tuning?

Comment: You should provide a small example that can be use for tests. Beside this what do you mean by page geometry? which values do you want to change?

Comment: If you want the entire section on one page, you can use standalone.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/244348/make-only-one-page-for-each-chapter

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I edited my question. Can you help?

Comment: you don't want a new geometry, you simply want a \vspace*: `\newcommand{\sectionbreak}{\clearpage\vspace*{2.5cm}}`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thank you very much...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need for separate geometries for section and non-section pages. Instead, override the sectional command to insert an appropriate `\vspace*` at the top of the page. The following implements that under the default `article` class:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\let\oldsection\section
\renewcommand{\section}{%
  \par
  \clearpage
  \vspace*{\dimexpr25mm-\baselineskip-3.5ex}% \section in article adds 3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex
  \oldsection
}

% Add a vertical rule from the top of the page at lengths 25mm and 50mm, for reference
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\AddToShipoutPictureFG{%
  \AtPageUpperLeft{%
    \hspace{25mm}%
    \rule[-25mm]{1pt}{25mm}%
    \hspace{2mm}%
    \rule[-50mm]{1pt}{50mm}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\section{First section}\lipsum[1-10]
\section{Second section}\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

The removal of `3.5ex` comes from the [`article` class](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls?view=co)' definition of `\section` that adds a vertical skip of `3.5ex` (+ `1ex` - `.2ex`); see [Where can I find help files or documentation for commands like `\@startsection` for LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31780/5764):

```
\newcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                                   {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                   {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                                   {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}}
```