# Papersize: page as long as document

Tags: geometry, paper-size, layout

Is it possible to have a document in which the paper size expands as long as the document goes and only breaks to the next page on `\newpage` or similar command?

#### Example of usage

A simple example of what i want to use this for is to have a list of exercises document where a page spreads to an exact number of questions, instead of having blank spaces or dividing the question in two pages.
Or simply have one page for every question where the page have the size of the question + its solution.

#### Update 1

As pointed in the [Question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/244348/make-only-one-page-for-each-chapter) linked by John Kormylo the class was changed from `article` to `standalone` with the `multi={minipage}` flag, that divided the document in `minipages` which was useful but broke the document layout.

This is the MWE, main points of the output is that the `fancyhdr` lines aren't aligned and somewhat out of the page and the page number is nowhere to be found
[image: PDF output]

```
\documentclass[
    class={article},
    multi={minipage},
    border={1cm},
]{standalone}



% xparse - multiple optional arguments
\usepackage{xparse}



\setlength\textwidth{240mm}
% % Geometry
% \usepackage{geometry}
% \geometry{
%     % papersize = {300mm, 400mm}, % ( 4:3 ) SVGA x 0.5
%     % papersize = {240mm, 320mm}, % ( 4:3 ) SVGA x 0.4
%     % papersize = {120mm, 640mm}, % ( 2*4:3/2 )
%     papersize = {180mm, 240mm}, % ( 4:3 ) SVGA x 0.3
%     % papersize = {229mm, 305mm}, % ( 4:3 ) ArchA/Arch1
%     % papersize = {320mm, 512mm}, % (16:10)
%     % papersize = {280mm, 448mm}, % (16:10)
%     % papersize = {240mm, 384mm}, % (16:10)
%     % a4paper,  % {210mm, 297mm}, % (√2:1 ) A4
%     % papersize = {180mm, 1000mm}, % LONG ( 4:3 ) SVGA x 0.3
%     top       = 21mm,
%     bottom    = 21mm,
%     left      = 5mm,
%     right     = 5mm,
%     portrait  = true,
% }



% fonts
\usepackage[fontsize=12pt]{fontsize}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}



% Linguagem
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel} % Babel



% Table of contents
\usepackage{tocloft}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}    % remove subsubsection from toc

% part
\renewcommand\cftpartfont{\bfseries}
%\renewcommand\cftpartafterpnum{\vspace{0mm}}
\setlength\cftbeforepartskip{1ex}

% sec
\renewcommand\cftsecfont{}                          % Font
\renewcommand\cftsecpagefont{}                      % page number font
\renewcommand\cftsecleader{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} % Dots
\setlength\cftbeforesecskip{0.5ex}
\setlength\cftsecindent{0mm}
%\setlength{\cftsecnumwidth}{25mm}                  % Fix section width

% subsec
\setlength\cftsubsecindent{0mm}
%\setlength{\cftsubsecnumwidth}{15mm}

% tab (table)
\setlength\cfttabindent{0mm}




% Multicols
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\columnsep}{.05\textwidth}
\multicoltolerance = 200

% toggle multicols  on/off
% \renewenvironment{multicols}[1]{}{\relax}


% titlesec
\usepackage{titlesec}

% Reset section on part
\counterwithin*{section}{part}

% Spacing: \titlespacing*{<left>}{<before>}{<after>}[<right>]
\titlespacing*{\part}      {0pt}{ 0pt}{0pt}
\titlespacing*{\section}   {0pt}{10mm}{0pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{ 5mm}{0pt}

% Part customization
\titleclass{\part}{straight}
\titleformat{\part}
    [block]                         % shape
    {\Large\bfseries\color{green}}   % format
    {\thepart\hspace{.5em}{--}}     % label
    % {\thepart}                      % label without --
    {.5em}                          % sep
    {\Large\bfseries}               % before-code
    [\vspace{1em}]                  % after  code



% siunix: SI units
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{
    % scientific / engineering / false / fixed
    scientific-notation    = engineering,
    exponent-to-prefix     = false,          % 1000 g -> 1 kg
    % exponent-product       = *,             % x * 10^y
    round-mode             = places,        % figures/places/none
    round-precision        = 2,
    output-exponent-marker = {\,\mathrm{E}},
}
% \DeclareSIUnit\atm{atm}
% \DeclareSIUnit\calorie{cal}
% \DeclareSIUnit\Torr{Torr}
% \DeclareSIUnit\bar{bar}
% \DeclareSIUnit\mmHg{mmHg}
% \DeclareSIUnit\molar{M}



% % Maths
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, bm}
\usepackage{derivative} % Derivative
\usepackage{mathtools}



% tcolorbox
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{
    breakable,                % allow page break
    % minted, xparse, listings, % code minted
}
\tcbset{ every box/.style = {
    coltext      = black,           % text  color
    % coltitle     = black,           % title color
    % fonttitle    = \bfseries,       % title font
    notitle,                        % Remove title
    opacityfill  = 0.1,             % white opacity
    opacityframe = 0,               % frame      opacity
    colback      = black,      % white color
    colframe     = black,      % border     color
    arc          = 3mm,             % Curvature
    width        = \linewidth,      % Width
    top          = 3mm,             % Space between text and top
    bottom       = 3mm,             % Space between text and bottom
    before upper = {\parindent2ex}, % Paragraph indentation
    before skip  = 0mm,             % Set vspace before box
}}



% mytitle and myauthor
\newcommand\mytitle   {{title here}}
\newcommand\myauthor  {{DJ}}
\newcommand\mycreator {{DJ}}
\newcommand\mysubject {{subject here}}
\newcommand\mykeywords{{{Keywords}}}

% title, author and date
\title{\huge\bfseries\color{green}\mytitle}
\author{\Large\myauthor}
\date{\Large\today}



% fancyhdr - Header and Footer customization
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % Clear
\fancyhead[R]{\normalsize\thepart}
\fancyfoot[L]{\normalsize\myauthor}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
\renewcommand\footrulewidth{.5pt}
% Marks 
% \renewcommand{\partmark}[1]{\markboth{}{\thepart#1}}



% hyperref
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    % Links customization
    % hidelinks   = true,
    colorlinks  = true,
    linkcolor   = green,
    anchorcolor = green,
    urlcolor    = green,
    % Metadata
    pdfinfo = {
        Title    = \mytitle,
        Author   = \myauthor,
        Creator  = \mycreator,
        Subject  = \mysubject,
        Keywords = \mykeywords,
    },
    % PDF display customization
    pdfpagelayout      = {OneColumn},
    pdfstartview       = {FitH},
    pdfremotestartview = {FitH}
    pdfdisplaydoctitle = true,
}
% Fix links when reseting section on part
\renewcommand\theHsection{\theHpart.\arabic{section}}

% Color targets
\let\oldhypertarget\hypertarget
\renewcommand\hypertarget[3][Link]{\oldhypertarget{#2}{\textcolor{#1}{#3}}}




% Divisions customization
\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{(\roman{subsubsection})}
% \renewcommand\thepart{Part \arabic{part}}



\begin{document}

% Title
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \maketitle

    % Table of Contents
    \renewcommand\contentsname{} % remove title

    \begin{multicols}{2}[\section*{Conteúdo}]
        \tableofcontents
    \end{multicols}
\end{minipage}

    \noindent\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
        \section{Questão}
        \begin{tcolorbox}
            \subsection*{Calcule o trabalho posto em jogo no percurso 2\to3.}%
            \vspace{2ex}
            \begin{flalign*}
                &
                    W_{
                        (30.2\to120.6)\si{\celsius}
                        P_{cnt}
                    }
                    = \int_{Vol_1}^{Vol_2} P_{ext}\odif{Vol}
                    =  P_{ext}\int_{Vol_1}^{Vol_2}\odif{Vol}
                    =  P_{ext}\adif{Vol}\big\rvert_{Vol_1}^{Vol_2}
                    = &\\&
                    =  P_{ext}\left(
                        Vol_2 - Vol_1
                    \right)
                    % = &\\&
                    =  P_{ext}\left(
                        \frac{n\,R\,T_2}{P_2} 
                        - \frac{n\,R\,T_1}{P_1}
                    \right)
                    =  n\,R\,\left(
                        T_2 - T_1
                    \right)
                    = &\\&
                    =  (1)\,(\num{8.314462618})\,\left(
                        (120.6+273.15) - (30.2+273.15)
                    \right)
                    \cong
                    \num{751.6274206672}
                &
            \end{flalign*}
        \end{tcolorbox}
    \end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Celdor, I think OP wants to have a very long page, like webpages on the browser, with size adjusting with its contents up to new page command.

Comment: Yes and no. No, because the maximum height of a page is `\maxdimen`. A larger page height is not possible. But if this is enough, it should be possible to work temporary with this maximum and change the page height to the real height in the output routine. I expect, that this could be done using the generic hooks (see `lthooks-doc.pdf` and `ltshipout-code.pdf`). And AFAIR I've already seen a solution some time ago. Unfortunately, I cannot find it.

Comment: Somewhat related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/244348/make-only-one-page-for-each-chapter

Comment: I would say it is more than just somewhat related @JohnKormylo, probably if the OP here would use minipages with `standalone` then that would be a solution.

Comment: It is indeed perfectly related the question @JohnKormylo linked, thank you for the find, 
my `questions` are already wrapped in a environment that uses `minipage` so i just need to accommodate that in my document, i use quite some of the features of the `article` class ill need some help to create a new class that has the features i use. is there a way for me to use the articles class instead of the standalone?

Comment: actually i use the `subfile` class and package to join many tex files, so that i can have many lists in the same pdf, how could i apply this solution whilst maintaining the `subfiles` package and class?

Comment: The [class=article] option for \usepackage{standalone} will load all the definitions used by article class (page 8-9).

Comment: i tested changing the **main file** class to `standalone` and indeed it separated the questions in pages, but the pages in a really bad shape most of the content is off the page

Comment: The only thing with bad alignment is the `fancyhdr` package and lines, ill open a new question issuing this problem in particular. Using the `standalone` class with the `multi={minipage}` option solved this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is the same as [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/244348/make-only-one-page-for-each-chapter)

Unfortunately the `fancyhdr` package looses its alignment so it was removed.

Fixing the MWA with the solution works as follows:

```
\documentclass[
    class={article},
    multi={minipage},
    border={1cm},
]{standalone}



% xparse - multiple optional arguments
\usepackage{xparse}



\setlength\textwidth{240mm}
% % Geometry
% \usepackage{geometry}
% \geometry{
%     % papersize = {300mm, 400mm}, % ( 4:3 ) SVGA x 0.5
%     % papersize = {240mm, 320mm}, % ( 4:3 ) SVGA x 0.4
%     % papersize = {120mm, 640mm}, % ( 2*4:3/2 )
%     papersize = {180mm, 240mm}, % ( 4:3 ) SVGA x 0.3
%     % papersize = {229mm, 305mm}, % ( 4:3 ) ArchA/Arch1
%     % papersize = {320mm, 512mm}, % (16:10)
%     % papersize = {280mm, 448mm}, % (16:10)
%     % papersize = {240mm, 384mm}, % (16:10)
%     % a4paper,  % {210mm, 297mm}, % (√2:1 ) A4
%     % papersize = {180mm, 1000mm}, % LONG ( 4:3 ) SVGA x 0.3
%     top       = 21mm,
%     bottom    = 21mm,
%     left      = 5mm,
%     right     = 5mm,
%     portrait  = true,
% }



% fonts
\usepackage[fontsize=12pt]{fontsize}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}



% Linguagem
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel} % Babel



% Table of contents
\usepackage{tocloft}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}    % remove subsubsection from toc

% part
\renewcommand\cftpartfont{\bfseries}
%\renewcommand\cftpartafterpnum{\vspace{0mm}}
\setlength\cftbeforepartskip{1ex}

% sec
\renewcommand\cftsecfont{}                          % Font
\renewcommand\cftsecpagefont{}                      % page number font
\renewcommand\cftsecleader{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} % Dots
\setlength\cftbeforesecskip{0.5ex}
\setlength\cftsecindent{0mm}
%\setlength{\cftsecnumwidth}{25mm}                  % Fix section width

% subsec
\setlength\cftsubsecindent{0mm}
%\setlength{\cftsubsecnumwidth}{15mm}

% tab (table)
\setlength\cfttabindent{0mm}




% Multicols
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\columnsep}{.05\textwidth}
\multicoltolerance = 200

% toggle multicols  on/off
% \renewenvironment{multicols}[1]{}{\relax}


% titlesec
\usepackage{titlesec}

% Reset section on part
\counterwithin*{section}{part}

% Spacing: \titlespacing*{<left>}{<before>}{<after>}[<right>]
\titlespacing*{\part}      {0pt}{ 0pt}{0pt}
\titlespacing*{\section}   {0pt}{10mm}{0pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{ 5mm}{0pt}

% Part customization
\titleclass{\part}{straight}
\titleformat{\part}
    [block]                         % shape
    {\Large\bfseries\color{green}}   % format
    {\thepart\hspace{.5em}{--}}     % label
    % {\thepart}                      % label without --
    {.5em}                          % sep
    {\Large\bfseries}               % before-code
    [\vspace{1em}]                  % after  code



% siunix: SI units
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{
    % scientific / engineering / false / fixed
    scientific-notation    = engineering,
    exponent-to-prefix     = false,          % 1000 g -> 1 kg
    % exponent-product       = *,             % x * 10^y
    round-mode             = places,        % figures/places/none
    round-precision        = 2,
    output-exponent-marker = {\,\mathrm{E}},
}
% \DeclareSIUnit\atm{atm}
% \DeclareSIUnit\calorie{cal}
% \DeclareSIUnit\Torr{Torr}
% \DeclareSIUnit\bar{bar}
% \DeclareSIUnit\mmHg{mmHg}
% \DeclareSIUnit\molar{M}



% % Maths
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, bm}
\usepackage{derivative} % Derivative
\usepackage{mathtools}



% tcolorbox
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{
    breakable,                % allow page break
    % minted, xparse, listings, % code minted
}
\tcbset{ every box/.style = {
    coltext      = black,           % text  color
    % coltitle     = black,           % title color
    % fonttitle    = \bfseries,       % title font
    notitle,                        % Remove title
    opacityfill  = 0.1,             % white opacity
    opacityframe = 0,               % frame      opacity
    colback      = black,      % white color
    colframe     = black,      % border     color
    arc          = 3mm,             % Curvature
    width        = \linewidth,      % Width
    top          = 3mm,             % Space between text and top
    bottom       = 3mm,             % Space between text and bottom
    before upper = {\parindent2ex}, % Paragraph indentation
    before skip  = 0mm,             % Set vspace before box
}}



% mytitle and myauthor
\newcommand\mytitle   {{title here}}
\newcommand\myauthor  {{DJ}}
\newcommand\mycreator {{DJ}}
\newcommand\mysubject {{subject here}}
\newcommand\mykeywords{{{Keywords}}}

% title, author and date
\title{\huge\bfseries\color{green}\mytitle}
\author{\Large\myauthor}
\date{\Large\today}



% fancyhdr - Header and Footer customization
% \usepackage{fancyhdr}
% \pagestyle{fancy}
% \fancyhf{} % Clear
% \fancyhead[R]{\normalsize\thepart}
% \fancyfoot[L]{\normalsize\myauthor}
% \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
% \renewcommand\footrulewidth{.5pt}
% Marks 
% \renewcommand{\partmark}[1]{\markboth{}{\thepart#1}}



% hyperref
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    % Links customization
    % hidelinks   = true,
    colorlinks  = true,
    linkcolor   = green,
    anchorcolor = green,
    urlcolor    = green,
    % Metadata
    pdfinfo = {
        Title    = \mytitle,
        Author   = \myauthor,
        Creator  = \mycreator,
        Subject  = \mysubject,
        Keywords = \mykeywords,
    },
    % PDF display customization
    pdfpagelayout      = {OneColumn},
    pdfstartview       = {FitH},
    pdfremotestartview = {FitH}
    pdfdisplaydoctitle = true,
}
% Fix links when reseting section on part
\renewcommand\theHsection{\theHpart.\arabic{section}}

% Color targets
\let\oldhypertarget\hypertarget
\renewcommand\hypertarget[3][Link]{\oldhypertarget{#2}{\textcolor{#1}{#3}}}




% Divisions customization
\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{(\roman{subsubsection})}
% \renewcommand\thepart{Part \arabic{part}}



\begin{document}

% Title
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \maketitle

    % Table of Contents
    \renewcommand\contentsname{} % remove title

    \begin{multicols}{2}[\section*{Conteúdo}]
        \tableofcontents
    \end{multicols}
\end{minipage}

    \noindent\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
        \section{Questão}
        \begin{tcolorbox}
            \subsection*{Calcule o trabalho posto em jogo no percurso 2\to3.}%
            \vspace{2ex}
            \begin{flalign*}
                &
                    W_{
                        (30.2\to120.6)\si{\celsius}
                        P_{cnt}
                    }
                    = \int_{Vol_1}^{Vol_2} P_{ext}\odif{Vol}
                    =  P_{ext}\int_{Vol_1}^{Vol_2}\odif{Vol}
                    =  P_{ext}\adif{Vol}\big\rvert_{Vol_1}^{Vol_2}
                    = &\\&
                    =  P_{ext}\left(
                        Vol_2 - Vol_1
                    \right)
                    % = &\\&
                    =  P_{ext}\left(
                        \frac{n\,R\,T_2}{P_2} 
                        - \frac{n\,R\,T_1}{P_1}
                    \right)
                    =  n\,R\,\left(
                        T_2 - T_1
                    \right)
                    = &\\&
                    =  (1)\,(\num{8.314462618})\,\left(
                        (120.6+273.15) - (30.2+273.15)
                    \right)
                    \cong
                    \num{751.6274206672}
                &
            \end{flalign*}
        \end{tcolorbox}
    \end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]