# How to make my entire document to fit into a single PDF page?

Tags: pdf, size

I have a rather long document that normally renders as two pages. Now, I want a single page PDF document to be generated instead. In other words, I want a PDF of A4x2 size. How would you do it?

It's possible to do it after compilation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507766/merge-convert-multiple-pdf-files-into-one-pdf

Comment: Note: A4 x 2 = A3

Comment: @PaulGaborit not if joined on the short side, which is I think required here

Comment: @yegor256 Do you want to have the two pages joined on a single sheet, without changing the typesetting? On which side would you like the two A4 to be joined? A3 landscape orientation, or a sheet 21 x 59,4 cm? Anyway, have a look to `pdfpages` package.

Comment: @lacobus1983 I expect my pages to go one after another in a long vertical document. If there would be five pages in the document, I want them to rendered as a very tall vertical PDF.

Comment: Somewhat related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/244348/make-only-one-page-for-each-chapter  You can use includegraphics to copy one page at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To illustrate my comment:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\pages}{6}% number of pages
\newcommand{\filename}{pecha.pdf}% filename of document

\newcounter{pdfpage}
\newsavebox{\tempbox}
\savebox{\tempbox}{\includegraphics[page=1]{\filename}}% get width of document

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{\wd\tempbox}
\loop\ifnum\value{pdfpage}<\pages\relax
  \stepcounter{pdfpage}%
  \includegraphics[page=\thepdfpage]{\filename}\par
\repeat
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simpler solution that does not need two separate compilations of two separate documents:

1. Intercept every page when it is shipped out,
2. add it to a box and
3. shipout the box at the end of the document.

The package [AtBegShi](https://ctan.org/pkg/atbegshi) makes the first step very easy, and the second step can be taken care of with the normal (plain) primitives.

```
% PACKAGE CODE

\RequirePackage{atbegshi}
\RequirePackage{luatex85}

\newbox \fulldocument

\AtBeginShipout{%
    \global\setbox\fulldocument=\vbox\bgroup
        % previous pages
        \unvbox\fulldocument
        % a line between pages
        \hrule width \pdfpagewidth
        % the current page
        \vbox to \pdfpageheight\bgroup
            % we have to position it like tex does
            \vskip \dimexpr \pdfvorigin + \voffset
            \moveright \dimexpr \pdfhorigin + \hoffset
                \box\AtBeginShipoutBox
            \vss \egroup
    \egroup \AtBeginShipoutDiscard}

\AtEndDocument{\par\break
    % spacing has already been applied manually
    \pdfhorigin = 0pt
    \pdfvorigin = 0pt
    \hoffset = 0pt
    \voffset = 0pt
    % set the new page height
    \pdfpageheight = \ht\fulldocument
    % output the full page
    \AtBeginShipoutOriginalShipout
        \box\fulldocument}

% DOCUMENT CODE

\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Page 1
\newpage
Page 2
\newpage
Page 3

\end{document}
```