# Is there a document class as described in this question?

Tags: page-numbering, document-classes

I am writing notes for self-lecture on a computer screen on a daily basis (attending math courses). I never intend to print these notes on paper, so the concept of "pages" is quite annoying ; I am always having issues with page breaks because of my big diagrams and self-made environments. Is it possible to have the equivalent of the article class "without pages"? In other words, the equivalent of [this format](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/) without the "being online" part. I want a file that I can read the entire text just by scrolling without any pages. Does that exist?

Comment: This seems to be the same question as at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64284/is-there-a-documentclass-that-produces-endless-pages

Answer (score 3):

It is impossible to make the page infinitely long, hovever the maximal length is a distance of about 18.892 feet (5.7583 meters). Hence you can write in the preamble e.g. `\textheight570cm`, which should be enough. I would however recommend smaller values, slightly above the real space needed.

Comment: How many ''pages'' is 5.7 meters? I mean, I write an entire course of notes, this is sometimes 60,80, 100 pages. If I can bring two or three courses together it could be more (for easy cross-referencing). Or I guess I could put one of these huge pages per chapter, which wouldn't be so bad. Would that work? Can the length of the page be variable?

Comment: Under this scheme, each page would be 5.7 meters long. So you will only have page break issues every 5.7 meters.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva A normal page, with 1 inch margins, has about 25 cm. Hence 5,7 m is over 22 pages.

Comment: @Przemyslaw : I'll page break at every section or chapter or so, it should be okay :D thanks a lot! I'll try it out on latex when I start studying again and tell you how it went.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke : It doesn't work. The content of the page gets longer, but the page preserves its size and the content gets cropped when it goes below the page height.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva But the second depend on the used previewer. In many of them there is a possibility  of setting page dimensions.

Comment: ''Previewer''? You mean the program I used to look at the pdf file? I use document viewer, but honestly I don't think this has anything to do with it.