# What documentclass to use for publications not meant to be printed

Tags: document-classes, output, documentclass

I'm looking for a documentclass or a setup where the paper size (like A4) and "page breaks" aren't part of the output.

How do I end up with one long pdf, with no page distraction?

Comment: Define `page gaps`? Have you ever heard of the `openany` class option?

Comment: I think the OP meant page breaks. Since I almost never print my LaTeX-produced documents, I've wondered the same thing myself on occasions.

Comment: Yes, excatly page breaks.

Comment: Not exactly the same, but possibly helpful: [Is there a documentclass that produces 'endless' pages?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/64284)

Comment: @barbarabeeton I think that is just what I'm looking for. Will test and see if it works as I hope.

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust the page dimensions with the `geometry` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[paperheight=100cm,margin=2cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\blindtext[20]
\end{document}
```

[image]