# How to create one long running page per chapter?

Tags: pdf, page-breaking, paper-size

How can I approach my idea of generating one large `PDF` "page" per chapter. The "paper" should be as long as it is required for the text, but if needed I can trim it afterwards.

I have a standard book with `30-60` chapters each `20-80` pages. As an illustration I'd like to generate two things:

- A thumbnail of each chapter: `128px or 256px` wide and as long as needed for the text. There should not be any headers, footers or headlines, etc inside the thumbnail
- One long `PDF` page, similar to the thumbnails, but in original size. This is only to explore the idea and not needed.

Any idea how I can approach this?

Comment: does this help? [How define a fixed width page, but length > some minimum length, but only as long as needed](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19672/579)

Comment: Note that TeX's pagesize is limited to ca. 5m by 5m, so your 80-page-long-pages are not doable.

Comment: What could the point of such thumbnails possibly be?