# How can I write a document with just one large page (no page breaks)?

Tags: page-breaking

I would like to write a notes sheet without any pages. In other words, I want to make sure that there are no page breaks, and no spaces between where a page break would go. For example, this is part of my current document:

[image: Excerpt from document]

the top part is part of Page 1, and the bottom part is part of Page 2. I found out how to remove page numbers using the nopageno package, but it didn't remove the space. How can I do that?

Comment: Welcome! There is a technical limitation on the vertical size, about 3.5 meters. Anyway, the topic has already been touched on the site: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19672/4427 https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27041/4427

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/244348/make-only-one-page-for-each-chapter.